# Data Synchronization between Mobile App and Cloud

Tags: android, ios, mysql, synchronization, cloud

Well, I'm building a app in both iOS and Android and both app needs to be syncronized with the cloud DB MySQL. Both the apps works offline so I need all the insert and update functionality. Delete is probably not going to be used but still I'd like to know.

Well, what I'm looking here is the solution or ideas or algo that's needs to done to achieve this.

I have kept CreatedOn and LastSync as timestamp column on each table.

Now the problem is should I always keep checking all the rows and all the columns everytime?

What I think is I should keep ModifiedOn column on all the tables and check that with LastSync for every device id. What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the answer you are waiting for, but on the project I'm working on, we are using Azure Mobile Services.  There is an Android and iOS SDK where they implemented synchronization between offline database and Azure (just like in Git you can call push and pull methods).

There are some limitations (TableStorage is a limited MSSQL storage), but you should check it out.

Comment: Sure, if I plan to use Azure, then I'll go for it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's about two years overdue , but I've been doing the same thing (Android App that syncs with web api and postgresql)

What I do up to now (still researching if it's the best way, which is how I found this question) is that I keep a last_update field with a timestamp on when the data was last_updated and an altered field with a boolean on whether the data was altered (by a user action on the device)

So when I perform the sync:

- I first copy the database to a backup (in case there is a problem)
- I send all the rows that are marked as altered (the server handles conflicts)
- then delete them
- after that I find the max(last_update) value,
- I subtract one minute from it
- Then request all rows that have been updated after that value,(this will also also include the data I have sent because there is no way , unless there is a problem, that a row is set to altered with a last_update before the last non altered row)

It may cause some duplicate data being transfered (especially if you make A LOT of changes frequently) but in my case it's a rare phenomenon